# Generalization of fixpoint subgroup and Knaster-Tarski

Tags: category-theory, fixed-point-theorems, universal-algebra

The Knaster-Tarski theorem states that the set of fixed points of a monotone function on a complete lattice forms a complete sublattice.

In group theory, the set of fixed points of an automorphism of a group forms a subgroup, called the fixpoint subgroup.

Are these both instances of some more general theorem about equational theories?

Comment: The set of fixed points of a monotone function on a complete lattice need not form a sublattice.

Comment: it at least forms a subposet, but I guess that ruins the equational theory aspect